# Remove CSS (dynamicly loaded, compiled, not link tag) from web page

Tags: javascript, css

I've got LESS/CSS file that is loaded on the client and the final CSS is produced. For loading I use some js library (like requireJS). So I dont have "link" tag for this CSS on may page to use approach with: **document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].disabled = true;**

Is there some way (hack) to remove fully remove this **CSS Embedded Styles** from web page? (I want to dynamicly replace it with other version, but If I dont remove the old one the new CSS classes will just overlay old ones. That is not what I want.

May me something browser depended, I develop with firefox with firebug, I can access and Edit this CSS from firebug, I wonder if there's programmatic way of doing it in my java script code.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the css in a style tag? Did you do a "view source"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
for (var s in styles) {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
}
```

?

Comment: Yes I've solve it, need to remove it for example with jquery $("style").remove().